# value binding to property in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, displayfor

I have a view model having 2 properties: one is a list of items class objects and the other one is an object of order class. I want to show the sum of the price calculated from items' list in `order.price`

Here is view model:

```
public class PlaceOrderViewModel
{
    public Orders Order { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Here is items model:

```
public class Items
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ItemType { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

I am looking for something like this,

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Order.Price, new { Value = @Model.Items.Sum(s => s.Price)})
```

I did try this but this doesn't work for me.

I want to bind the sum value with the `order.price` property.
Any help?

Comment: `DisplayFor()` does not generate a html element - just text (your `new { Value = @Model.Items.Sum(s => s.Price) }` does nothing because only inputs have a `value` attribute). You can use `<div>@Model.Items.Sum(s => s.Price)</div>` or better, set the value of `Order.Price` in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
    ...
    public int TotalPrice 
    {
        get
        {
             return Items == null ? 0 : Items.Sum(p => p.Price);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view should have:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Order.TotalPrice)
```